# strip comma's from a file

Tags: python, list, strip

```
txt = open("document.txt").read()

spt = txt.split()

new_list = []

for i in spt:
    if i.endswith(','):
        w=i.rstrip(',')
        new_list.append(w)
    elif i.endswith('.'):
        w=i.rstrip('.')
        new_list.append(w)
    else:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

I'm trying to go through my "document.txt" word by word and strip any comma at the end of the word. This is a learning exercise for me. I know there are "better" shorter ways to do this but I'm trying to learn the in's and out's of python. I have seen a lot of code on here that touches on this question, but I'm still having a hard time getting it to compile Anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know I have not declared a j iterator for my list. That is where I'm currently stuck. When I try to initialize that variable inside the for loop and/or next to my list I get a IndexError: list index out of range. I have played with this code for too long and am becoming overly Frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

That can be do with something like:

```
with open('document.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_list = [line.rstrip(',') for line in f]
```

Comment: Unfortunately with that it's not stripping off the commas and I don't know why.

Comment: @TonyG80 I had the wrong (left vs right) side.  I edited.

Comment: I tried the code you put in, thanks for you help. However that approach is not working. I did however get my for loop to work correctly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `.append()` function to add the items to the end of your new_list. 
Right now you are trying to access an index j in the list which does not exist because the list initialized to be of size 0.

Example of how to add an item i to the end of the new_list:

```
new_list.append(i)
```

Comment: The i.lstrip(',') doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for the help I'm not getting a compile error but the comma's are not getting taken off.

Comment: I think that's because you should be using `rstrip()` to remove the commas from the end of the string. `lstrip()` is used to remove chars from the start of a string.

Comment: I guess I need to pay closer attention to detail. That was the problem and it works now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = open("document.txt").read()

spt = txt.split()

new_list = []

for i in spt:
    if i.endswith(','):
        w=i.rstrip(',')
        new_list.append(w)
    elif i.endswith('.'):
        w=i.rstrip('.')
        new_list.append(w)
    else:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```